# Stack overflow while serializing user-defined Ruby objects to Riak

Tags: ruby, class, stack-overflow, riak

While working through http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/taste-of-riak/querying-ruby
I noticed what I can't store Time object in riak for some reason.

```
[3] pry(main)> client = Riak::Client.new(:protocol => "pbc", :pb_port => 8087, :host => "192.168.145.34")
=> #<Riak::Client [#<Node 192.168.145.34:8098:8087>]>
[4] pry(main)> 
[5] pry(main)> 
[6] pry(main)> tt = client.bucket('test')
=> #<Riak::Bucket {test}>
[7] pry(main)> v = tt.new("ttt")
=> #<Riak::RObject {test,ttt} [#<Riak::RContent [application/json]:nil>]>
[8] pry(main)> v.data = 1
=> 1
[9] pry(main)> v.store
=> #<Riak::RObject {test,ttt} [#<Riak::RContent [application/json]:1>]>
[10] pry(main)> v.data = Time.now
=> 2014-06-22 11:34:01 +0400
[11] pry(main)> v.store
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
from /home/maus/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:353
```

After that I discovered what it's the case for user defined classes too:

```
[16] pry(main)> class Tst
[16] pry(main)*   def initialize(x)
[16] pry(main)*     @x = x
[16] pry(main)*   end  
[16] pry(main)* end  
=> nil
[17] pry(main)> t111 = Tst.new(111)
=> #<Tst:0x9b13f4c @x=111>
[18] pry(main)> v.data = t111
=> #<Tst:0x9b13f4c @x=111>
[19] pry(main)> v.store
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
from /home/maus/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/pry-0.10.0/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:353
[20] pry(main)> 
[21] pry(main)> v.data = [1,2,3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
[22] pry(main)> v.store
=> #<Riak::RObject {test,test_key} [#<Riak::RContent [application/json]:[1, 2, 3]>]>
```

Looks like something is terribly wrong with my install. But how to investigate it? I'm using riak-1.3.2 and ruby 1.9.3p194 with the following versions of gems:
i18n-0.6.9
builder-3.2.2
beefcake-0.3.7
multi_json-1.10.1
innertube-1.0.2
riak-client-1.4.4.1

Comment: `SystemStackError` simply means that there is a (quasi-)infinite recursion going on; Ruby then throws an exception after 10000 recursive calls or so.

Answer (score 2):

The only place in the `store` method code path were I see the value being use is in `BeefcakeProtobuffsBackend.ObjectMethods::dump_object` which instantiates an `RpbContent` with `:value => maybe_encode(robject.raw_data)`, so this would appear to be an issue with serializing the custom data.

`RContent.raw_data` calls [`Serializers::serialize`](https://github.com/basho/riak-ruby-client/blob/master/lib/riak/serializers.rb#L14-L16)

```
def serialize(content_type, content)
  serializer_for(content_type).dump(content)
end
```

Serialize only understands a very few content types:

- Serializers['text/plain'] = TextPlain
- Serializers['application/json'] = ApplicationJSON
- Serializers['application/x-ruby-marshal'] = ::Marshal

The default for `content_type` is `application/json`, whose [dump](https://github.com/basho/riak-ruby-client/blob/master/lib/riak/serializers.rb#L14-L16) method is:

```
  def dump(object)
    object.to_json(Riak.json_options)
  end
```

Check that `v.raw_data` returns the value you expect, and if not, try setting `v.content_type='text/plain'`

For your custom class, make sure it has a `to_json` or `to_s` method that returns a string, and select the appropriate content_type.